# How can I install GRUB for just one partition?

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, grub

I just got a new Windows 10 computer (dell Inspiron) and am looking to start dual-booting, but I want to be sure I don't destroy the bootable sector of my PC. 
The Inspiron BIOS has a UEFI boot selector which currently displays "Windows Boot Manager" and $nameofmybootableusb. They both boot fine, but when I install Linux (Mint) I want to be able to select either GRUB or Windows Boot Manager from this window,  where WBM boots to Windows and Grub boots to Mint.
I realize that this is likely a complicated request, so thank you in advance for any help you can offer!
[Picture of the BIOS screen, if that's helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEev5.jpg)

Comment: Read `info grub2`. There is a section on installing on your system. You can specify a device, which will be your target partition.

Answer (score 0):

Make an external boot media  (USB or Optical) and put a GRUB loader on that.  Configure to allow booting the fixed disk partition of interest.   Assuming your boot drive order works to allow that, use that media as a key to boot your alternate system.

I modified a Ubuntu boot image to allow that sort of thing